# No CurrentSessionContext configured (use hibernate.properties)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I decided to learn hibernate. Everything starts small, so I created the simplest program, but I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:498)
> at ua.com.auvin.Main.main(Main.java:13)

I use hibernate.properties. It is located in: src/main/resources:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Main program:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Product product = new Product("name", 10, "name2");
        System.out.println(product);
        session.save(product);
        System.out.println(product);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
```

Class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;


@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    
    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String name, int price, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

with the following versions of hibernate, the same error: 5.6.5.Final, 5.6.9.Final

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```